# How can I setup a Svelte input bind:value={v}, when v is a map of map?

Tags: svelte

In [this "playground"](https://github.com/stephane-klein/poc-svelte-input-bind-map-map), I'm trying to edit the data of **a map of map** (see [`src/routes/+page.svelte`](https://github.com/stephane-klein/poc-svelte-input-bind-map-map/blob/4ac94d503d78d7605848b2edfc17fccdb98423c5/src/routes/%2Bpage.svelte#L4)).

I'm aware of the ["Bind to a Map() Object not possible #5721"](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/5721) issue, but while I'm waiting for it to be completed, and also for my personal culture, I'd like to find out how to implement it.

Source code extract:

```
<script>
    import { range } from 'radash';

    let myMap = new Map([
        [
            2021,
            new Map([
                [1, "a"],
                [2, "b"],
                [3, "c"],
                [4, "d"],
                [5, "e"],
                [6, "e"],
                [7, "e"],
                [8, "e"],
                [9, "e"],
                [10, "e"],
                [11, "e"],
                [12, "e"]
            ])
        ],
        [
            2022,
            new Map([
                [1, "a"],
                [2, "b"],
                [3, "c"],
                [4, "d"],
                [5, "e"],
                [6, "e"],
                [7, "e"],
                [8, "e"],
                [9, "e"],
                [10, "e"],
                [11, "e"],
                [12, "e"]
            ])
       ],
       [
           2023,
           new Map([
                [1, "a"],
                [2, "b"],
                [3, "c"],
                [4, "d"],
                [5, "e"],
                [6, "e"],
                [7, "e"],
                [8, "e"],
                [9, "e"],
                [10, "e"],
                [11, "e"],
                [12, "e"]
           ])
       ]
    ]);

    console.log(myMap);
</script>

<p>Editable table:</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        {#each Array.from(range(1, 12)) as month}
            <th>{month}</th>
        {/each}
    </tr>
    {#each myMap.entries() as [year, yearMonth]}
        <tr>
            <th>{year}</th>
            {#each yearMonth.entries() as [_, v]}
                <td>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        bind:value={v}  // <== this problem is here
                        style="width: 4em"
                    />
                </td>
            {/each}
        </tr>
    {/each}
</table>

<p>View Table:</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        {#each Array.from(range(1, 12)) as month}
            <th>{month}</th>
        {/each}
    </tr>
    {#each myMap.entries() as [year, yearMonth]}
        <tr>
            <th>{year}</th>
            {#each yearMonth.entries() as [_, v]}
                <td>
                    {v}
                </td>
            {/each}
        </tr>
    {/each}
</table>
```

How can I implement the equivalent of `bind:value={v}`?

Answer (score 2):

If you have to keep Map as a data structure, the most reasonable approach is to just not use `bind:`. You can always split that into data in & event out. I.e.

```html
{#each myMap.entries() as [year, months]}
    <tr>
        <th>{year}</th>
        {#each months.entries() as [month, value]}
            <td>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    {value}
                    on:input={e => {
                        months.set(month, e.target.value);
                        myMap = myMap; // force update
                    }}
                    style="width: 4em"
                />
            </td>
        {/each}
    </tr>
{/each}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c2c823c40aa64937a88d72e067824177?version=4.2.0)

Answer (score 1):

Would recommend just *not doing that*.

The only thing I could come up with to make this work with `bind:`, that may or may not work in all cases (probably the latter), is proxying the Map instances, so they behave like regular objects.

A rough implementation of that:

```js
function mapProxy(obj) {
    // Properties appear to be converted to string.
    // Without conversion the numbers are not found in Map.
    const parseProp = prop => {
        const parsed = parseInt(prop);
        return isNaN(parsed) ? prop : parsed;
    }

    const handler = {
        get(_, prop) {
            const key = parseProp(prop);
            let value = obj instanceof Map && key in obj == false ?
                obj.get(key) : obj[key];

            if (typeof value == 'function')
                // Otherwise function is called on Proxy, throwing an error
                value = value.bind(obj);

            return mapProxy(value);
        },
        set(_, prop, value) {
            const key = parseProp(prop);
            if (obj instanceof Map && key in obj == false)
                obj.set(key, value);
            else
                obj[key] = value;

            return true;
        }
    };

    if (typeof obj != 'object')
        return obj;

    return new Proxy(obj, handler);
}
```

```js
let myMap = mapProxy(new Map(...))
```

This should work recursively automatically; if anything that is an object is returned, it will be wrapped in the proxy.

You then can iterate the keys and index into the map:

```html
{#each [...myMap.keys()] as year}
    <tr>
        <th>{year}</th>
        {#each [...myMap[year].keys()] as month}
            <td>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    bind:value={myMap[year][month]}
                    style="width: 4em"
                />
            </td>
        {/each}
    </tr>
{/each}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/58e121ac3cd64c23a80f537624d31e47?version=4.2.0)

This will not work for non-primitive keys (which is *what Map is for*) and if you have keys that can be parsed to integers but are not an integer in the Map.

So, again, don't do this. Use regular objects or do not use `bind:`.